# Using the ternary operator for multiple operations

Tags: c#, operators

How can I use the ternary `? :` condition to perform multiple operations, if expression is true/false?

`wbsource = (exp) ? (Do one thing) : (Do second thing)`
`wbsource = (exp) ? (Do one thing) (Do second thing) : (Do second thing)`

For eg:

Why can't I perform three operations between `?` and `:`

```
filename = (fp!=null) ? fp; Properties.Settings.Default.filename=fp; Properties.Settings.Default.Save; : Properties.Settings.Default.file;
```

With simple if condition, I would have written in a simple way like:

```
if(fp!null)
{
filename = fp;
Properties.Settings.Default.filename;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
else
{
filename = Properties.Settings.Default.file
}
```

What's a sweet short way to write using the above ternary operator?

Comment: I like the if / else way in this case - much easier to read IMHO...

Comment: Unary means "with one operand". `? :` has *three* operands - it's a *ternary* operator, and its name is the conditional operator.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Why can't I perform three operations between ? and :

Because these are *operands*, which are *expressions*. Each expression evaluates a value; you want multiple *statements*. From Eric Lippert's [blog post about `foreach` vs `ForEach`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx):

> The first reason is that doing so violates the functional programming principles that all the other sequence operators are based upon. Clearly the sole purpose of a call to this method is to cause side effects.
>
> The purpose of an expression is to compute a value, not to cause a side effect. The purpose of a statement is to cause a side effect. The call site of this thing would look an awful lot like an expression (though, admittedly, since the method is void-returning, the expression could only be used in a “statement expression” context.)

You should absolutely write this using an `if` block. It's clearer.

If you *really, really* want to use the conditional operator for this, you could write:

```
// Please, please don't use this.
Func<string> x = () => {
    Properties.Settings.Default.filename = fp;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    return fp;
};

string filename = fp == null ? Properties.Settings.Default.file : x();
```

Comment: Why not declare the function anonymously inline (joke)

Answer (score 17):

The conditional operator, which is a ternary operator (not a unary operator), is not a replacement for an `if` statement. It is an operator that returns one of two results. While you can chain this to some extent:

```
var result = someBool ? "a" : (otherBool ? "b" : "c");
```

That gets a little hard to read. Further, you're trying to call the `Save()` function, which does not return a result, hence you cannot use it with this operator.

Answer (score 4):

If this was `c` you'd be OK thanks to the ["comma operator"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator):

```
int b;
int a = (1==1) ? (b=6, somemethod(), 1) : (b=7, 2);
```

Here `b` will be set to 6, `somemethod` will be called and then `a` is set to 1.

Thankfully that was one feature that was not ported over, use `if..else` it's much clearer.

Answer (score 2):

If you really, really want to, you could use a function which has [side effects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)):

```
filename = (fp!=null) ? DoOneThing(...) : DoAnotherThing(...);
```

Though whoever maintains your code won't thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, use an `if` block, its the only sane thing to do.

Other answer, for the dirty, smelly insane individual.

```
filename = (fp!=null) ? Func<string> {fp = Properties.Settings.Default.filename; Properties.Settings.Default.Save; return fp;} : Properties.Settings.Default.file;
```